# wxWidget app hangs when response from backend takes long time

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am using `wxWizard`, in my 3rd page I need to call a function from backend, when that function takes long time to send response, my app hangs and shows not responding in title. Once that response is recieved from backend function, app behaves normally. why this is happening? Am I doing something wrong? How should I make that app not to hang? Response from backend function is delayed because of some network issue or long processing time in backend.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/961910/740065). Following is an extract:

> An application gets the events from a queue provided by Windows.
>
> If the application doesn't poll the eventqueue for a while (5 seconds), for example when doing a long calculation, then Windows assumes that the application is hung and alerts the user.
>
> To avoid that applications should push expensive calculations to worker threads or split up processing and make sure the queue gets polled regularly.

So, the problem with your code is that, In your program there is only one thread,the *main* thread. It is taking care of all the activity e.g. UI update, event handling, responding users etc (which are very less time consuming). But when use it comes to *handle* connection with backend server, it is *time consuming*. So, **you should use another thread to handle network operations**. In this way *main* thread will be available for its normal work and not show that it is not responding.